# Was any investigation done in the aftermath of Jurassic Park?

Tags: jurassic-park

In *Jurassic World:Dominion*, Lewis Dodgeson is the head of Biosyn and is quite prosperous.

Was there no investigation done as to what happened that after the events of *Jurassic Park* (1993) in which many were killed and which was a quite costly project? Was it all just written off as an accident?

I understand that people just assumed that the storm caused all of it, but still didn't the outside world or the investors want to know how the dinosaurs escaped and how their representatives died?

I am mainly interested in the movies, as I consider it a plothole as to how Dodgeson made it out safe and went on to become the head of Biosyn.
But if unavailable I'll accept answers from the novel as well.

Answer (score 11):

I don't think this was explicitly addressed in the movies. In *Jurassic Park: The Lost World* it seems that Ingen enforced NDAs on everyone involved but nothing is suggested of governmental involvement.

In the original novel, however, things are quite different.

After escaping Isla Nublar, the survivors are rescued by the Costa Rican Air Force, which declare the island hazardous and proceed to bomb it with napalm.

The survivors are then detained by the United States and Costa Rican governments at a hotel on the mainland for several weeks.

Dr Grant is eventually visited by an official who tells him that an unknown pack of animals has been migrating through the Costa Rican jungle, eating lysine-rich crops and small animals, indicating the dinosaurs may have escaped the island's destruction.

Comment: Costa Rica doesn't have an Air Force.

Comment: @DJClayworth Costa Rica also doesn’t have dinosaurs.

Comment: well, Ingen is just another private company so i dont think so. Further did the costa rican airforce interrogate the survivors?

Comment: @SethMMorton You make an excellent point.